Sun light not showing in render
so I am totally new to Blender and I have a little problem with the sunlight. I modeled a enclosed room and the sunlight is outside of it, Shining through openings. I sed my sunlight as desired in the viewport but when i start rendering the sunlight isn't visible. And when i close the render and go back to the viewport I see that the sun moved away from its original spot where i have installed it.
Can someone please help me?
Desired position of the sun before rendering:

Rendered image and the sunlight isn't visible

After closing the render image the sun has moved away


Could you provide your Blender file, using https://blend-exchange.com/, substituting a plain cube to the whole building, but keeping the whole "lightning" system ?
